# How to get equivalent of pandas melt using groupby + stack?

Tags: python, pandas

Recently I am learning groupby and stack and encountered one method of pandas called melt. I would like to know how to achieve the same result given by melt using groupby and stack.

Here is the MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,   1,   1,   2,   2],
                   'B': [1,   1,   2,   2,   1],
                   'C': [10,  20,  30,  40,  50],
                   'D': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']})

df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='A',value_vars=['B','C'],var_name='variable',value_name='value')

print(df1)
   A variable  value
0  1        B      1
1  1        B      1
2  1        B      2
3  2        B      2
4  2        B      1
5  1        C     10
6  1        C     20
7  1        C     30
8  2        C     40
9  2        C     50
```

How to get the same result using groupby and stack?

## My attempt

```
df.groupby('A')[['B','C']].count().stack(0).reset_index()
```

I am not quite correct. And looking for the suggestions.

Comment: Notice that since `pandas 0.20.0` pandas has a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) method for dataframes, so we can rewrite your code: `df.melt(id_vars='A',value_vars=['B','C'],var_name='variable',value_name='value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not need groupby, just [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
result = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].set_index('A').stack().reset_index().sort_values(by='level_1')
result.columns = ['A', 'variable', 'value']
```

**Output**

```
   A variable  value
0  1        B      1
2  1        B      1
4  1        B      2
6  2        B      2
8  2        B      1
1  1        C     10
3  1        C     20
5  1        C     30
7  2        C     40
9  2        C     50
```